# Rubymotion, adding interface builder: running a rake task from gem gives "Don't know how to build task 'ib'"

Tags: ruby, interface-builder, rake, rubymotion

I have a Ruby Motion project, and I want to add Interface Builder to it.

I've added the gem:
`gem 'ib'`
But when I run `bundle exec rake ib`, I get `Don't know how to build task 'ib'`

Does any one know what I might be doing wrong? here is my gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rake"
gem "ProMotion", '~> 2.0'
gem "ProMotion-push", git: 'git@github.com:BananaNeil/ProMotion-push.git', :branch => 'actionable-push-notifications'
gem "cocoapods"
gem "motion-cocoapods"
gem 'xcodeproj'


gem "bubble-wrap-http", git: 'git@github.com:BananaNeil/BubbleWrap-HTTP.git', branch: 'allow_invalid_ssl_certs'
gem "bubble-wrap"
gem "sugarcube" # monkeypatch all the things
gem "motion-yaml"

gem "motion-stump"
gem 'houston'

# Enter debugger with simple syntax
gem 'dbt' #-----> break

# Add pretty print
gem 'motion-pp'

# Handle address book for us
gem 'motion-addressbook'


gem 'ib'
```

Comment: Sometimes the Rakefile silences errors coming from `require "bundler" / Bundler.require`. Remove the begin/catch code surrounding those lines, and make sure everything is getting require'd correctly. Just a thought!

Comment: Also it's cool to see `dbt` in use! I rely on it heavily for debugging, but not sure whether many other people use it or not. 

Comment: @colinta Total PEBKAC error, its been ages since I have added a gem to this project, and I totally forgot that I am specifically requiring each gem in my rake file (mostly so I only pull in specific sugarcube packages). I forgot to add the `require 'ib'`. If you want to write your comment as an answer.. or even just write: "Make sure its being required in your rake file", I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: If you want, you can specify the sugarcube packages in the Gemfile: `gem "sugarcube", require: ["...","..."]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to `require 'ib'` inside the Rakefile, either with Bundler or manually for each gem.

And if you use Bundler, you might need to remove the `begin/catch` guard, because it will silence all import related errors.